# android text color

Tags: android, user-interface, text, textview, uicolor

Is it possible to have different colored texts within the same text view?

I've been trying to use the Spannable class to style my texts but the documentation is completely useless on how to style text with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml`, the `font` tag and the `color` attribute...

```
String s = "<font color='#FF0000'>I'm read</font> <font color='#0000FF'>and I'm blue</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Comment: I was fruitlessly using `<span style="color:red">` style of formatting so thanks for the pointer on using the `font` tag.